# Listview blanks when using navigator pop

Tags: react-native

I am facing two problems & can not resolve this. Can anyone explain why this is happening? Or can anyone give me the solution?

Problem NO 1:
There are two components 1) Home 2) Inner
In the Home there are list of data & when I click any one of them it route to Inner. There are also a back button with using navigator pop. There is the issue sometime reproduce - When I click on back, it routes to Home but there is no data(listview element) but when I touch on the screen the data shows properly.

Problem NO 2:
In the home component within the list data, there also some repeated data within the single row.
I have used map function for this. Sometimes ( Most of the time it shows correctly ) it is also not shown in list view, the row is showing properly but the repeated data are missing.

```
<ListView onEndReached={this.props.reloadArticles} onEndReachedThreshold={10} dataSource={this.props.dataSource} renderRow={this.renderPost} enableEmptySections={true} refreshControl={ <RefreshControl refreshing={this.props.isRefreshing} onRefresh={this.props._onRefresh} /> } />
```

Answer (score 0):

NO 1:

Sounds like this: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/8607
If you use rn 0.4.0 setting initialListSize={0} could help

NO 2:
Could you please post your renderRow / dataSource code

Answer (score 0):

@SnowMax Sorry for late reply & thanks for help.

Due to confedential project I could not share all code but I can share u the code structure:

```
   renderPost = (list, sectionID, rowID) => {
     if(list && list.is_shared_post == true){
        return (
            <WallShared list={list} rowID={rowID}  /> 
        ); 
     }
 }
class WallShared extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
    render() {
        if( this.props.list.is_shared_post == true){
                    switch(this.props.list.TblPostsComments.post_type){
                    case 'T':
                    return (<ShareText  list={this.props.list}  />); 
                    default:
                    return (<ShareDefault list={this.props.list} rowID={this.props.rowID}  />);
                    break;
                  }
        } else {
                  return (
                    <View>something</View>
                  )
         }
  }
}
export default WallShared;

    class ShareText extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state ={
          isLoggedIn:false,
        }
      }
    componentDidMount(){
      }
    render() {

        var ShareBlock = this.props.list.TblPostsComments.shared_contents.map(function(cont, ind) {
                return (
                   <View style={[styles.feedItem, styles.SfeedItem]} key={ind}> </View>
                );
        },this);
        return(
              <View style={styles.feedItem}>
                <View style={styles.sharedWrap}>
                  { ShareBlock }
                </View>
              </View>  
        );
      }
    }

    export default ShareText;
```